# How to add datalabels to chartJS on Primefaces

Tags: primefaces, chart.js

I'm creating charts with the new ChartJS lib on Primefaces, but I could not find a way to add the value as label on the bar chart or line chart.

Looking on the internet, I've found a JS plugin called [chartjs-plugin-datalabels](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels)! that does what I need.

How could I use this plugin on my Java Primefaces application?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this...

1. Add the script to your XHTML page:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2.0.0"></script>
```

2. In your Java model for your chart set the Extender feature on.

```java
chartModel.setExtender("chartExtender");
```

3. In your XHTML add this JavaScript code function to match when you set in #2 Java bean.

```js
function chartExtender() {
   var options = {
      plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
      options: {
         plugins: {
            // Change options for ALL labels of THIS CHART
            datalabels: {
               color: '#36A2EB'
            }
         }
      },
      data: {
         datasets: [{
            // Change options only for labels of THIS DATASET
            datalabels: {
               color: '#FFCE56'
            }
         }]
      }
   };

   //merge all options into the main chart options
   $.extend(true, this.cfg.config, options);
};
```

This was all based on their configuration guide https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.com/guide/getting-started.html#configuration  But this should at least get the plugin going.

Comment: Isn't the first assignament useless? As `options` variable gets assigned a different value on the next line

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped me to migrate from pf 10.0.0 to pf 11.0.0