# How to show percentage (%) using charts chartsBar in primeFaces jsf

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces, chart.js

I came to know that chartjs-plugin-labels is best to display percentage instead of count values inside angles or outside the angle but unfortunately no code snipped found for PrimeFaces JSF chartJs as shown in the following figure . enter image description here

```
barModel2.setExtender("chartExtenderPercentage");
```

after research I find that function barModel.setExtender("functionJSName) in ManagedBean
which is to execute the JS function in the XHTML file.

The result obtained

[image]

Numbers and percentages I couldn't show

[[image: [The result I want to reach]]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @JasperdeVries I clarified a little

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add datalabels to chartJS on Primefaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55765518/how-to-add-datalabels-to-chartjs-on-primefaces)